# Splitting strings/tokens

Tags: java, string, tokenize

Is there a better way to read tokens in a file in java?
I am currently using StringTokenizer for splitting the tokens. But it can be quite inefficient in most cases as you have to read token by token.

Thank you

Comment: *"quite inefficient in most cases as you have to read token by token"*, how else would you like to do it then? I mean, how else are you going to "discover" your tokens except scanning the entire input string/stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [`StringTokenizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) in the Java API you will notice that it recommends an alternative:

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that
>   is retained for compatibility reasons
>   although its use is discouraged in new
>   code. It is recommended that anyone
>   seeking this functionality use the
>   `split`  method of `String` or the
>   `java.util.regex` package instead.

If neither of these options suit your needs, you should take a look at [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), which also supports pattern matching:

```
  Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File("example.txt"));
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      // do some stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the StringUtils.split() in Apache's Jakarta classes.  It lets you write code like this:

```
String[] splitStrings = StringUtils.split(unsplitString, "|");
```

Let's you avoid regex, and it deals with null pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best and most flexible option for this is [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class. With it, you have a lot of control over how you split a string, and it returns an `Iterable<String>` of the tokens resulting from a split. You didn't really specify what exactly it is you want to do for which reading token by token is "inefficient", but if you'd prefer a `List` for example, you could just convert the `Iterable` to a list using `Lists.newArrayList(Iterable)` or `ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterable)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more details, but is simple cases [split](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html) works quite well.